# VLAN interface on router (not subinterface)

Tags: router, vlan

Why VLAN interface can be created on router? Is this, by any chance, for router that supports switch module?

Note: This is not about subinterface. On the router, VLAN can be created like in switch.

Comment: I think we need some more information to answer your question properly. The idea of non-VLAN routing interface (non-subif) on a router makes no sense from a network engineering perspective.

Comment: I think your thought process is accurate, though the question is a little unclear. What you're referring to is called a [SVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_virtual_interface).

Comment: @nullmem I do not know what more information I can provide. But that is it. I can add VLAN on the router and IP address (quite different from switch) too.

Comment: @Fizzle I wonder what is the difference between the VLAN interface and subinterface. I tried to use the VLAN interface (or SVI as you said) and disable the subinterface only to result of routing failure.

Comment: @Fizzle Maybe due to the lack of caffeine this morning I totally missed that and I believe your correct, he is referring to an SVI. I gave you a vote up for the catch.

Comment: Are you looking to create a routing BVI (bridge virtual interface)? http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/integrated-routing-bridging-irb/17054-741-10.html

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

A vlan interface in a router is used with the switch modules, or HWIC.  Once you create the SVI (vlan interface), you can create an access port on one of the switchports, and the vlan will be created, or if using a trunked switchport, you have to manually add the vlan.